ServiceCircularReferenceException due to "State service now uses a cache collector for performance"
The change described in State service now uses a cache collector for performance added in 10.3 (issue: use cache collector for state) causes the kernel tests of a module to break:
25) Drupal\Tests\datetime_testing\Kernel\TestDateTimeTest::testConstruct with data set "14" ('+2 hours', 'UTC', 1489323845, 1489331045)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceCircularReferenceException: Circular reference detected for service "cache_factory", path: "cache_factory -> datetime_testing.test_time -> state -> cache.bootstrap -> cache_factory".
/builds/project/datetime_testing/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/CheckCircularReferencesPass.php:67

(test pipeline here)
The service definition for datetime_testing.test_time:
services:
  datetime_testing.test_time:
    class: Drupal\datetime_testing\TestTime
    public: false
    decorates: datetime.time
    decoration_priority: 5
    arguments: ['@datetime_testing.test_time.inner', '@state']

I don't understand how this dependency loop is being generated. The state service is injected into datetime_testing.test_time, and the decorated datetime.time only makes use of Symfony's RequestStack.
Can the state API still be used when decorating another service, or do I need to use the KeyValueStore instead like this issue (which suggests that the change from State to KeyValueStore was done because of infrequent access, which is not the case here)?

I don't understand how this dependency loop is being generated.
The error message:

Circular reference detected for service "cache_factory", path:
"cache_factory -> datetime_testing.test_time -> state ->
cache.bootstrap -> cache_factory".
/builds/project/datetime_testing/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/CheckCircularReferencesPass.php:67

The cache factory is referencing your version of the time service which is referencing the state service that in the current version since 10.3 is referencing the caching system which then is referencing the cache factory again. The problem is that there are now a lot of services depending on the time service and if you add higher-level services to this low-level service the risk is very high one of those services is causing a circular reference.
